# Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to null://mailhog:1025

Tags: php, symfony, email, laravel-8, mailhog

I'm getting an error in mailhog while sending an email.

**Error:**

```
Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to null://mailhog:1025 (Unable to find the socket transport "null" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)
```

**my code :**

```
Mail::to('sample@example.com')->send(new MessageMail($message));
```

**and .env config:**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@site.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I use docker and my laravel version is 8, PHP Version 7.4.10 as well
I am migrating from symfony to laravel.

Comment: you can turn encryption off by setting `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=` in the .env file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated by [Ken Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11854986/ken-lee) in the comments:

You're using an invalid value (`null`) for `MAIL_ENCRYPTION`.

```bash
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Use an empty value instead for `MAIL_ENCRYPTION`:

```bash
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

Answer (score 0):

Close The Serve than Run:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

and still you facing this issue close the project and Run it again.
I hope it's Work and you don't need to do any changing in .env

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. There's an accepted answer on this question, which means that the OP could resolve the problem with the details given there. What makes you think that a completely different answer works in the same way?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).